# project.c:43:68: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘->’ token

Tags: c

I dont understand what is the problem with the ->? I want to give the variable Number_Line the value of  -1

> project.c:43:68: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘->’ token
>    Entry_Machine_Code *new_entry = NULL, *entry_head = NULL; new_entry->Number_Line = -1; entry_head->Number_Line = -1;

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
#define Array_Size 100

typedef struct entry_machine_code{
    char entry_Name[Array_Size];
    int Number_Line;
    struct entry_machine_code *next;
}Entry_Machine_Code;

Entry_Machine_Code *new_entry = NULL, *entry_head = NULL; new_entry->Number_Line = -1; entry_head->Number_Line = -1;
//                                                      error here ^^
```

Comment: I can't see it at first glance, but once you've got this compiling it won't run: you need to allocate some memory for these structures before you set properties on them, you can't assign them to NULL then try to use them.

Comment: Is this at the top level scope of the file? You can't write assignment instructions like that outside a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your last line is adding newlines to cut it:

```
Entry_Machine_Code *new_entry = NULL, *entry_head = NULL;
new_entry->Number_Line = -1;
entry_head->Number_Line = -1;
```

the first line define and initialize global variables, but the last two lines must be placed in a body, not at global level, the compiler does what it can to understand.

Visibly you use *gcc* and yes the messages produced by the compiler are funny

---

Out of that if you place these lines in a function and execute it you will have an other problem dereferencing NULL in the two last lines

Comment: Thanks for helping Bruno and Rup